# How old are Stefan and Damon?

Tags: the-vampire-diaries

In *The Vampire Diaries*, how old were Stefan and Damon when they were turned? They both had a relationship with Elana. I know that Stefan says he's 17, the same age as Elana. Is it true? And how old is Damon? And, if Stefan isn't 17, how old was he when he was turned?

Answer (score 2):

- Stefan Salvatore "is" 17

  According to the [wikia](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Stefan_Salvatore), he was born on 1 November 1846, and became a vampire on 25 September 1864. So he was 17 years old, near 18.

  According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_Salvatore), he was born on 5 November 1846, and became a vampire in 1864. The month is not specified, but it says he was 17.
- Damon Salvatore "is" 25

  According to the [wikia](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Damon_Salvatore), he was born on 18 June 1839, and became a vampire on 25 September 1864. So he was 25 years old.

  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_Salvatore) does not give dates.

Comment: I always thought that Damon was younger brother..

Comment: Wikias are generally not reliable sources, since anyone can edit them and sometimes people do edit nonsense or fanon into them.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an error somewhere.

Lily Salvatore died (was turned) in May 1858, which would make Damon 18yrs 11 months and Stefan (born November 1847) 10yrs 6 months. There are three different birth dates for Stefan, November 1846 with two different days in November and November 1847. As Stefan celebrates 162 years in 2009, that would make his birth date 1847. That still makes Damon 18, almost 19 (if Damon was born June 1839).

Throughout the series we are led to believe that when Lily dies, Stefan is 10 and Damon 17. I cannot seem to get this to add up. That would mean Damon was born 1840 and not 1839. Also what doesn't add up is this: we've established that Stefan is 10 when Lily dies in 1858 as this is mentioned. This would mean his birthday is 1847. If this is the case, if he is turned by Katherine in September 1864, he would only be 16 years old, almost 17. As Stefan tells Elena he was 17 when he turned, this would suggest that Stefan was born 1846, making him 11 when his mother dies.

Somewhere in the writing of TVD, an error has been made. The ages don't add up. If he was 17 in 1864, how can he celebrate being 162 in 2009? That would make him 163. Therefore we know he was born 1847, making him 16 when he was turned in 1864. Someone somewhere has really messed up these dates.

Answer (score -1):

Since Damon was 17 when Lily died in 1858, he would be 23 in 1864. There is 6 years between 1858 and 1864. 17+6=23. It also could depend on what month Lily died in. If it was after Damon’s 18th birthday, then he would be 24. But it couldn’t be since he was 17.

Comment: You don’t have to explain that there’s 6 years between 1858 and 1864 - it’s simple arithmetic.

Answer (score -1):

Damon was 17 when his mother died and Stefan was 10. So you would add how many years his mother had been dead. 1864-1858=6 which means 6 years later, that would make **Damon 23** and **Stefan 16**.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! What are your sources for this information?

Answer (score -2):

At Damon and Stefan's Mom's death, Damon was 17 and Stefan was 10, so that's 7 years apart. Add 7 years to that, so **Damon is 24** and **Stefan is 17** because he told Elena.

Comment: I don't see what this adds to the previous answer.

Comment: What do you mean? Ok all I am saying is I just finished TVD and saw the age of Damon and Stefan so Damon was 17 and Stefan was 10 so all I had to do was the math.

Comment: He means there is already an answer here that says exactly the same thing, but in a shade more readable format.

Comment: @Gallifreian I don't see how this answer says the same thing.  The other answer says they are 17 and 25, this one that they are 17 and 24.  I have no idea which is correct, but they are certainly different answers.

Comment: @Bamboo  -  true. I apologize then. Yet, this answer lacks referencing, punctuation, and basic grammar.

Answer (score -3):

Stefan is 17, Damon is 25.

Stefan turned 2 months before his 18th birthday, so pretty much the difference is 7 years, it just looks like 8 ...

Comment: Do you have any sources to support your answer?

Comment: yes...various pages such as http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Stefan_Salvatore and I have been watching TVD for days now... for like the millionth time