# Are the Salvatore brothers' ages inconsistent?

Tags: age, the-vampire-diaries

So in season 6 and 7 its mentioned a few times that when Lily, the brother's mother, dies Stefan is 10 and Damon is 17 - this was in 1858.

But if the dates are all correct for Stefan and Damon's birth (1846 and 1839), that makes Stefan 12 and Damon 19!

All the websites like the [Wikia](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/The_Vampire_Diaries_Wiki) are usually correct about date. Does that means the creators of Vampire Diaries made a massive mistake and aired the wrong ages... more than twice?

**Can anyone clarify whether the writers really got the ages wrong multiple times or if it's something else?**

Comment: May or may not be helpful, but you can have a year's worth of wiggle-room on ages based on when the date is relative to the person's birthday.  Two years is a bit much, though.

Comment: yeah no :/ did the maths, that's not it ta

Comment: Related [How old are Stefan and Damon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132979/how-old-are-stefan-and-damon)